# Find all solutions of $x^a + x^b + x^c + x^d = 75$ with constraints that $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Find all solutions of $x^a + x^b + x^c + x^d = 75$ with constraints that $x$ is an integer and $a,b,c,d$ are rational numbers.

I found 2 solutions:
$$
x = 2^n, a = \frac{6}{n}, b = \frac{3}{n}, c = \frac{1}{n}, d = 0, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+
$$
and
$$
x = 72^n, a = \frac{1}{n}, b = c = d = 0, n \in\mathbb{Z}^+
$$

Are there more solutions? If there is no other solution, how to prove? Thanks.

---

Thanks for @galoisgroup comments.

So the question can be paraphrase as:

Are there integers $(x, k, a, b, c, d)$ such that
$$
\left(\sqrt[k]{x}\right)^a
+\left(\sqrt[k]{x}\right)^b
+\left(\sqrt[k]{x}\right)^c
+\left(\sqrt[k]{x}\right)^d = 75
$$
where $x$ is not m-th power for any positive integer m > 1 and k > 1.

Comment: If $(x,a,b,c,d)$ solution then $(x^m,a/m,b/m,c/m, d/m)$ is solution. So we can assume that $x$ is not $m$-th power for any $m$.